# The value of my newly appended button returns undefined or nothing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I am trying to obtain the value of a newly appended button, however it always logs undefined or nothing. I have tried many methods, such as .val(), .textContent, and .value, as I have found those on here.

Here is my code.

```js
}).done(function (response) {
  var lat = response.data[0].latitude;
  var long = response.data[0].longitude;

  //Appends new button based on recent search
  searchHistory.append(`<button class="col-12 btn border-info m-1" id="prevSearch">${textInput.val().toLowerCase().split(' ').map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(' ')}</button>`);

  var previousSearch = $("#prevSearch");

  previousSearch.on('click', () => {
    console.log($(this).val();

    console.log(document.getElementById("prevSearch").textContent); 
  })
})
```

The first log under the click function returns undefined, while the second one returns the actual content. However it only works with the first button that is appended when I try a `console.log("test")`.

So in summary, I have 2 Issues, I can't get the value of the button and only the first button works when tested with a simple console log.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to what Phil has said, you have an error on the line `console.log($(this).val();` - missing closing parenthesis for the call to `console.log`

Comment: You have no value attribute on your button, so there is no `val` to return. If you are appending merry than one button the `id` attribute **MUST** be unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the button by ID. If you're adding multiple elements with the same ID, that won't work since IDs must be unique within the document.

As for your button value, I'd say just use `$(this).text()`. Browser support for the element content as `HTMLButtonElement.value` has a patchy history.

I'd just use the following

```js
const button = $("<button>", {
  type: "button",
  "class": "prevSearch col-12 btn border-info m-1",
  text: textInput.val().replace(/(^| )[a-z]/g, c => c.toUpperCase())
}).appendTo(searchHistory)

button.on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

---

You could also move the event handling to a delegated handler outside of this code that can handle all current and future button clicks

```js
searchHistory.on("click", ".prevSearch", function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much!